# Отследить конец ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

Есть ScrollView, В ней динамически RelativeLayout, которая только что (условно) было программно составлена. Нужно отследить тот момент, когда пользователь прокрутит этот ScrollView до конца. Именно упрется в конец. Как это изящно отследить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете добавить к вашему `ScrollView` `OnScrollChangeListener` и внутри него отследить когда ваш `SrollView` подойдет к концу.

```
scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                View view = (View) scrollView.getChildAt(scrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
                int diff = (view.getBottom() - (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView.getScrollY()));

                // если diff равен 0 - вы достигли конца скрола
                if (diff == 0) {
                    // some code
                }
            }
        });
```

Здесь есть только 1 проблема. Этот код работает только для API версии 23+. Если же вам нужно решение для более старых Android-ов, то тут будет сложнее:

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        int scrollY = rootScrollView.getScrollY(); // For ScrollView
        int scrollX = rootScrollView.getScrollX(); // For HorizontalScrollView
        // DO SOMETHING WITH THE SCROLL COORDINATES
    }
});
```

Вам придется ручками сохранять координаты и отслеживать конец скролла